# How to prevent automatic suspending / restore of applications?

Tags: mac, macos

I have a MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra (10.12.6). I have two user accounts, one for work and one for personal use. Both are signed in, with the work account having some Chrome windows, Eclipse and the development environment running, and the personal account having some Chrome windows.

Very often when I switch from one user to another, do a little something, and switch back, all applications have been suspended / killed / something, and are automatically restarted when I log in.  This messes up many apps, workspace locations etc.

Is there any way I can prevent this automatic suspension / whatever from happening?

My laptop has 16GB of RAM, so it should be sufficient for both users.  I haven't seen any significant memory hogs with the activity monitor.

Comment: To name a few issues: all Chrome windows are resized to stamp size, Eclipse is resized to display only the three window buttons, all terminal sessions are lost, iTerm2 goes weird and apps stop working inside it, all window locations are lost, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been fixed in High Sierra.

However, the whole system now occasionally freezes when switching users.

Comment: The freezing when switching users was resolved by disabling all software auto-updates.